# Create a JSON file of all installed dpkg software

Tags: text-processing, package-management, dpkg, json

I'm trying to collect all packages installed through dpkg in a JSON file.

I tried this script:

```
echo [ > installed_packages.json
dpkg-query -W -f '{"name":"${binary:Package}","version":"${Version}","short_description":"${binary:Summary}","description":"${Description}","author":"${Maintainer}","location":"${Filename}","status":{"want":"${db:Status-Want}","status":"${db:Status-Status}","eflag":"${db:Status-Eflag}"},"dependencies":"${Depends}","tags":"${Depends}"},\n' >> installed_packages.json
echo ] >> installed_packages.json
```

Though I quickly noticed that the placeholders are unescaped and some fields (like the dependencies) would need some processing to be really useful.

So I was thinking about just getting a simple list with the command `dpkg-query -W -f '${binary:Package}'` and iterating over it and process every field individually. Though I'm worried that is going to take a severe hit on the performance having 10ish `dpkg-query` calls per package.

So how could I achieve that in a as portable as possible way? (The script will end up as a part of a monitoring tool on many different machines. Support for other package managers will follow).

**EDIT:**

Since the placeholders seem to be designed to be RFC 822 compliant (and other software, like `apt-cache show <package>`, produces RFC 822 compliant output anyways), I think a `sh` solution to turn RFC 822 into JSON would be an amazing solution.

**EDIT 2:**

I just noticed that that would be nice, but sadly doesn't make processing individual values easier.

So like RFC 822 to properly escaped variables or something like that would what could make everything work.

**EDIT 3:**

Repediately calling `dpkg-query` absolutely kills the performance. Having a single call, makes the script run in far less than a second. Running it once for every packages makes the script take well above 30s with 100% CPU. That is not acceptable...

Answer (score 2):

A few months ago I wrote a simple ruby script to do a very similar job for our monitoring tool. I only needed the name and the version. I added the short_description and author. Any other fields may require more processing. It's a starting point for something you can build out if you wish.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'open3'
# json is only necessary for the pretty_generate at end, remove if not needed
require 'json'

allpkgs = {}
# Edit this command to serve your own purposes
cmd = ("dpkg-query -W -f='${binary:Package};${Version};${binary:Summary};${Maintainer}\n'")

dpkgout, stderr, status = Open3.capture3(cmd)
dpkgout.split("\n").each do |line|
  pkginfo = line.split(';')
  allpkgs[pkginfo[0]] = { 'version': pkginfo[1], 'short_description': pkginfo[2], 'author': pkginfo[3] }
end

# pretty JSON print, otherwise use 'puts allpkgs'
puts JSON.pretty_generate(allpkgs)
```

Comment: Nice and simple :-)
Are you not worried that someone will use `;` in the description?
Or is that allowed?

Comment: Re: Finding `;`s in the description field. This code is very (very) ad hoc, and  doesn't consider any cases like what you identified. The semi-colon is simply a token, and some other token `$%token^&` that would have a near-zero probability of appearing may in fact be better.